# create on fly captcha image on php

Tags: php, image, captcha

I have a code to create cpatcha image on the fly, it shows image as broken...here is the code

```
 $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
  /* font size will be 95% of the image height */
  $font_size = $height * 1;
  $image = imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD       image stream');
  /* set the colours */
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image,0, 0, 0);
  //      $text_color_2 = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 40, 20);
  $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 50, 40, 35);
  $line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 140, 135);
   //      $noise_color_2 = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 120, 100);
  /* generate random dots in background */
  for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/15; $i++ ) {
     imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1,  $noise_color);
  }
  /* generate random lines in background */
  for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
     imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height),     mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $line_color);
  }
  /* create textbox and add text */
  $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
  $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
  $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
  imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
  /* output captcha image to browser */
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
```

can anyone say whats wrong with my code?

Comment: stopped? come on you can do better than that

Comment: well....i really dont know what happened here...its creating image on the fly...can permissions be the problem?

Comment: Well I really dont know what **stopped** even means in this context

Comment: @Dagon image is curropted now

Comment: Open image in text editor.  Check top and bottom for php errors

Comment: @Dagon no php errors

Comment: When you write a question about an error, always __always__ include details of the error.Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the BOM character. I removed it and now it works fine.